# YQL console gives me result but rest query gives me error

Tags: datatable, yql

I'm trying to use YQL Console to get currency rates, the YQL statement is

```
select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("EURUSD","GBPUSD")
```

the console results give me

```
{
 "query": {
  "count": 2,
  "created": "2017-10-26T02:42:44Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "results": {
   "rate": [
    {
     "id": "EURUSD",
     "Name": "EUR/USD",
     "Rate": "1.1829",
     "Date": "10/26/2017",
     "Time": "3:42am",
     "Ask": "1.1829",
     "Bid": "1.1829"
    },
    {
     "id": "GBPUSD",
     "Name": "GBP/USD",
     "Rate": "1.3269",
     "Date": "10/26/2017",
     "Time": "3:42am",
     "Ask": "1.3269",
     "Bid": "1.3269"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

but the rest query gives me error

{"error":{"lang":"en-US","diagnostics":{"cache":{"execution-start-time":"0","execution-stop-time":"0","execution-time":"0","method":"GET","type":"MEMCACHED","content":"ENV.queryyahooapiscomproductionsg3.store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys.15a841ff462a38eb6175e73b4dc747ef"},"env":"Failed to read from storage: store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys: Invalid store url: store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys","warning":"Invalid environment specified: store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys"},"description":"No definition found for Table yahoo.finance.xchange"}}

Answer (score 0):

The `yahoo.finance.xchange` is a community table. In the YQL console there should be a checkbox saying `Show Community Tables` select that and you should have access to it. The REST call [here](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22EURUSD%22%2C%22GBPUSD%22)&diagnostics=false&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&format=json) works. Let me know if you have any questions.